# How to hide all group children using kinetic js

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have situation, where after fulfilling some condition I want hide all group children.

I use

```
group.hide();
```

and

```
group.getChildren().hide();
```

both the cases, the last element only hidden. I want hide all elements one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
group.getChildren().each(function(node){node.hide();});

layer.draw();
```

Comment: it is also hiding the last element only

Comment: donno why, but it wont works for me. it hide only the last element only. So, I solved this my moving the group to another layer and then I hide the layer.

Comment: Hmmm...none of that code deals with the group so it wouldn't affect hiding the group.  Just to clarify, please confirm that you have created a Kinetic.Group called "group"?  But, if by "group" you mean you want to hide all elements on grainLayer then you can hide all grainLayer elements with grainLayer.getChildren().each(function(node){node.hide();}); grainLayer.draw();

Comment: I have created a Kinetic.Group called "group". And I have several images like var test = new Kinetic.Image({       image: images[key],       x: anim.x,y: anim.y,height:60,width:55,draggable: true   
}); And I am adding these images to group as group.add(test) and then I add the group to layer, with layer.add(group). Except the hiding, all tasks working fine

Comment: That code snip looks ok.  Can you post a link to the whole batch of code that's misbehaving?